# React useQuery returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm new to useQuery and I'm facing some troubles trying to fetch data to a single page. The problem is: I must make two distinct requests in a page inside the same component. However, only one of the response are returning me data.

Here are the axios requests:

```js
export const getUserInfo = (userId: string) =>
  CobAPI.get<UserInfoResponse>(`/users/info/${userId}`);

export const getUserStatistics = (userId: string, quarter: number) => {
  CobAPI.get<UserStatisticsResponse>(`/users/statistics/${userId}/${quarter}`);
};
```

And here is the component:

```js
export const ProfilePage = () => {
  ...

  const userInfoResponse = useQuery(["user", userId], ({ queryKey }) =>
    getUserInfo(queryKey[1] as string)
  );
  const userInfo = userInfoResponse.data?.data;

  const userStatisticsResponse = useQuery(
    ["statistics", userId, quarter],
    ({ queryKey }) =>
      getUserStatistics(queryKey[1] as string, queryKey[2] as number)
  );
  const userStatistics = userStatisticsResponse.data?.data;
  
  ...
```

I can check in the network tab that both requests were successful and returned the expected JSON. However, if I console.log() the userStatisticsResponse, the data field is undefined.

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: getUserStatistics is not returning anything. u put braces accidently

Comment: can you show us an example return value for each api call with mock data?